# Accessing ruby method's symbol contained in a module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-2.2

Given Ruby 2.2

```
module A
  def self.a
    "a"
  end
end
```

How do I access `A.a` so I can assign to a variable and call it later?

I have tried the following:

```
x = A::a.to_sym
send x           # NoMethodError: undefined method `a' for main:Object
```

The following works:

```
x = -> { A.a }
x.call
```

Since I have both namespaced functions and non namespaced functions in an array is there a way I can do this with `send`?

I really don't want to pollute the namespace with `include A`

Comment: But what's ur intention.. why do u need to do that?

Comment: your code above works to access 'a', the problem is you're trying to call :a on main and that method doesn't exist there

Comment: songyy, I have an a list of functions that exist in different namespaces that I want to execute at a later time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a callable object (i.e. an object that supports `#call` just like a proc) using the [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method:

```
a = A.method(:a)
a.call # Or a[] or a.() as you prefer.
# "a"
```

Comment: Oops.. same time.. hi :)

Answer (score 2):

`A::a` is a method, so you can simple do:

```
m = A.method :a
m.call # returns "a"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `send`:

```
A.send :a  #=> "a"
```

or

```
A.send "a" #=> "a"
```